# Wordpress website doesn't show any content

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migration

I have built a pretty big wordpress website, and wanted to move to different hosting and domain...

I moved files, database, changed wp-config file and even changed all mentions of old domain to new one in the mysql database content.

Also, I had to change TYPE=InnoDB to ENGINE (manually), but I don't think it could cause some problems.

So, the problem is that, the website doesn't show any content, menues... etc. I can only see header and footer. Admin Panel works but when I go to pages/media It shows 0 result... nothing is there. However, phpMyAdmin shows that the pages, posts... etc. is on place.

What could the problem be?

Thanks

Comment: Did you just search/replace the old website url with the new url or did you take into account serialised arrays? I use this tool https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to account for serialised arrays

Comment: I searched and replaced in code editor... but it might not be a reason, as I tried original database version as well (without replacements) and it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in database compatibility, I set it as MySql323 and it worked for me.